# ''Forms' is an undeclared prefix.' Xamarin Forms and Microcharts

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm on Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2017 using xamarin forms and attempting to put the microcharts library over the top of it.

When I build the solution I'm getting the error ''forms' is an undeclared prefix.'

The XAML being referenced in the error is:

```
  <forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart1" HeightRequest ="150"/>
```

My code-behind is:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>
    {
        new Entry(200)
        {
            Color = SKColor.Parse("#FF1493"),
            Label = ""
        }
    };
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you have "forms" declared as an xmlns?

Comment: Here are the xmlns declarations:<ContentPage  `xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_My_Project's_Name"`

Comment: you don't have "forms" declared as a namespace - the README for Microcharts clearly shows how to do this

Comment: use `xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Microcharts.Forms;assembly=Microcharts.Forms" >` as @Jason said